# How to add an image to the middle of a MDTopAppBar in KivyMD?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I've made a KivyMD App which has a MDTopAppBar at the top of the screen. This topbar contains a button to open the main menu (added through `left_action_items` parameter).

But now, I want to add an image (*my_logo.png*) at the center of the topbar. The problem is that when I add the image, the topbar seems to be divided into two lines. At the top line I see the button and at the bottom line I see the image.

How can I put both at the same level in a "unique line"?

Here's the relevant part of the kv code:

```
Screen:
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDTopAppBar:
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
                        elevation: 2
                        Image:
                            source: 'my_logo.png'
                            pos_hint: { "center_x": .5, "center_y": 1 }
                    Widget:
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            ...
```